# Global Resources from class in App_Code

Tags: c#, asp.net, app-code

I've moved one of my classes to the App_Code folder (and namespace) and inside of this class I have a reference to a global resource:

```
using Res = myProjectName.App_GlobalResources.Validation;
```

Before I moved this class to the App_Code folder, everything worked alright. Now I get a runtime error stating that:

```
CS0122: 'myProjectName.App_GlobalResources.Validation' is inaccessible due to
its protection level
```

If I go into the designer code for the Validation.resx (Validation.designer.cs) and change the `internal class Validation` to be public (`public class Validation`) then it works fine.

How come I can't access this as normal from inside the App_Code folder?

Is it because the App_Code and App_GlobalResources content are dynamically compiled, and at runtime, App_Code is compiled first and my Validation Resx hasn't yet compiled?

Thanks for any answers.

Comment: You may take a look at [this article](http://altinoren.com/PermaLink,guid,5b69e6d6-86b0-4717-889a-94db78ff04b2.aspx).

Comment: Thanks Darin. I actually went ahead and manually replaced "internal" with "public" for this particular resource .cs file and that solded the problem. I assume that's the same thing this software does.

Answer (score 1):

You can also change Custom Tool in Properties of your resource file to "PublicResXFileCodeGenerator"